# What type of high temperature crimp connector is this?

Tags: connector, wiring, crimp

A heating element on a 3D Printer has coated stainless steel leads that were crimped to another wire. I cut the other wire but would now like to reconnect it.

I'd like to use the same type of crimp connector if possible - but have no idea what this connector is called or how to find it.

The wire is approximately 22-24 gauge.

What is this type of connector called? Where can I purchase it (or something similar)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bullet type crimp connector to me or maybe a small spade connector.

Comment: Maybe. Although the connector is just one piece - there aren't male/female ends - one wire goes in each side and then it was crimped. Hence why I had to cut it. Does that help?

Comment: is it possible that top male/female part was cut-off and this is just the tail end?

Comment: I imagine a bullet type crimp would closely match that.

Comment: nothing's been cut - that's the whole connector

Comment: non-insulated butt-splice? [https://www.google.com/search?q=uninsulated+butt+splice](https://www.google.com/search?q=uninsulated+butt+splice)

Comment: Thanks @ChrisKnudsen - looks like that's the ticket! How do I know the proper crimping tool to put these on?

Comment: The tool will vary depending on the manufacturer of the splice (from inexpensive to ridiculously costly).  One would typically pick the splice design that: you like, is available, is the right size, and fits your price point.  Then investigate the recommended 'tooling' that is compatible with the splice.  Sometimes there's a suggested cheaper 'prototyping' crimp tool (like some common Molex crimpers).  More often than not, the crimp manufacturers would prefer that you drop $500 on a spiffy ratcheting tool that provides a gas-tight crimp.  I've used everything from the spiffy kind to old pliers

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what is called a “parallel splice”.  If this is a high-temperature application then you want them made of nickel.  These can be hard to find in a variety of sizes, but a search of the popular distributors for “crimp nickel” or “splice nickel” should turn up something.